# Split numbers delimited by any non numeric string

Tags: c#, regex, split

I need to split a string with numbers separated by any non numeric string.
i.e.

```
"1111/222**3333333///44/ 55555"
```

I need to get the string array:

```
[0] 1111
[1] 222
[2] 3333333
[3] 44
[4] 55555
```

I have found a lot of regex examples, but no one is the right one.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not split on `\D+` or match all `\d+`?

Comment: Or do it by hand, walking the string as an `IEnumerable<char>` and using `char.IsDigit` and instances of StringBuilder (or even the same one)

Comment: If I match \d+ I get a string with all the numbers not an array with the separated number. If I split on \d+ I get an array with / ** /// /

Comment: The case matters between \d and \D. One is for matching digits, and one is for matching non-digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Regex.Split(String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Split_System_String_System_String_) splits an input string into an array of substrings at the positions defined by a regular expression pattern.

In your case, the pattern for any group of one-or-more non-digit characters would be `@"\D+"`, so your code would be like this:

```
const string pattern = @"\D+";
var input = "1111/222**3333333///44/ 55555";
var output = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Comment: Credit to @ggorlen for suggesting the simpler regex of  `@"\D+"` instead of `@"[^\d]+"`, which I had used originally.